# Azure Mobile Service, Got Access Token

Tags: c#, azure, mobile, service, windows-8.1

I have done stup for Azure Mobile Service for facebook, twitter , google and MS account. They are authenticating fine in a Windows store 8.1 App.

Now i have userid and access token. Next step is to get profile information from all these providers. I have no clue how to go about it, i tried google api with access token getting 401.

Azure mobile service documentation is incomplete, it doesn't have a sample to show how to communicate with these providers once authenticated.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/10/25/getting-user-information-on-azure-mobile-services.aspx

Idea is to get token from provider and respond back to client.

Comment: The information in the link provided is not valid anymore, there doesn't seem to be a way to retrieve the provider specific access token anymore...